# Display text in MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm building an MFC C++ application for one of my uni projects, and unfortunately MFC only allows you to use the `SetWindowTextW()` method, with a parameter of `LPCTSTR`?  not a `string` or `CString`, and for the life  of me I cannot find out how to convert my string to an `LPCSTR` value.

My code is:

```
pBorrowedBookCEdit1->SetWindowTextW(/* INSERT LPCTSTR HERE */);
```

The String comes from a completely separate object.

If there is another way of passing text to a `CEdit` object in MFC then please let me know =)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Please go concretely, and show some code you have tried in your question!

Comment: From `std::string` the `c_str()` method might be appropriate to convert to a `LPCSTR` value.

Comment: Here is an example of how to use the SetWindowTextW method for a Cedit object. (A CEdit is essentially a text box in MFC)

pBorrowedBookCEdit1->SetWindowTextW(INSERT LPCTSTR HERE);

Comment: where does the `string` come from?

Comment: @user258873 I wanted you to edit your question! Most code posted in comments is useless.

Comment: How would I go about implementing the "c_str()" method? =)

(Apologies but I'm only a novice programmer)

Comment: @user258873 **Again:** Edit your question please!! You don't need to implement just use it: [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: The string comes from a completely separate object, and is irrelevant to my issue.

I just want to display a string in a CEdit object.

Comment: _'The String comes from a completely separate object.'_ Which type of object, which type of member or member function call result?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Has answered the question below =), thanks for all the help everyone, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that you have a `std::string` on hand, which is vaguely indicated by your question, and assuming further that you're building a Unicode app, also vaguely indicated, then you can probably do

```
CString mfc_string( s.c_str() );
// Use mfc_string here.
```

where `s`  is the `std::string`.

The `CString` constructors are documented in [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314317%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

It's often a good idea to consult the documentation.

---

Background: `LPCTSTR` is a macro that expands to either `char const*` or `wchar_t const*` depending on whether the symbol `UNICODE` was defined when `<windows.h>` was included. It's a compatibility thing, for writing code that might work, with some drastically reduced functionality and reliability, in Windows 9x. Unless you're targeting Windows 9x, forget it, don't use the `T` macro stuff.

The `T` macros became obsolete already in the year 2000, when Microsoft introduced the Layer for Unicode which lets Unicode apps work in Windows 9x (with only slightly reduced functionality).

That they're still used for non-legacy code in 2014, long after the demise of the target platform, is, IMHO, a testimony to the extreme power and self-sustainability of conformity.

Comment: You are fantastic! Thank you so much!

Again, I apologize for my poor communication, and I'm sure I'll improve as time goes on =)